# Problem with controls using a user defined length

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following example shows my problem. Why is it not possible to use the length \xyz in this construct? And, of course, what do I have to do to make it work?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\xyz}
\setlength{\xyz}{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill (0,\xyz) to [controls={+(90:1cm) and +(90:1cm)}] (1,\xyz) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try with this syntax: `\fill (0,0+\xyz) .. controls +(90:1) and +(90:1) .. (1,0+\xyz) -- cycle;`

Comment: Just do `\newcommand{\xyz}{1}` unless you have reasons to stick to lengths.

Comment: Thanks, Juan, this really works! Won't you post it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: Thanks, Symbol 1. I don't really stick to a length, but as Juan's proposal works I will use the modified syntax.

Comment: also you can try `\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{declare function={xyz=1;}}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\fill (0,xyz) to [controls={+(90:1cm) and +(90:1cm)}] (1,xyz) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks, Black Mild. Interesting, I haven't known this feature before, but it seems like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer. I will keep it in mind for other usage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `\the\xyz`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\xyz}
\setlength{\xyz}{1cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill (0,\the\xyz) to [controls={+(90:1cm) and +(90:1cm)}] (1,\the\xyz) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill (0,1cm) to [controls={+(90:1cm) and +(90:1cm)}] (1,1cm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So simple! Many thanks for the advice.